# GCC linker issue with -lm flag

Tags: c, gcc, linker, makefile

I'm having issues with the GCC linker, specifically using the `-lm` flag since I'm using some functions from math.h. I get the following errors:

> main.c:(.text+0x8e5): undefined
>   reference to `floor'
>
> main.c:(.text+0x901): undefined
>   reference to `ceil'

Here's the relevant portion of my makefile:

```
myprogram: main.o
    gcc -Wall -pedantic -o myprogram main.o

main.o: main.c foo.h bar.h
    gcc -Wall -pedantic -lm main.c
```

Probably something silly I'm overlooking, but I'm definitely not an expert when it comes to makefiles.

Comment: Did you make sure to include math.h?

Comment: Related: *[Why do you have to link the math library in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033898/why-do-you-have-to-link-the-math-library-in-c)* (18 answers. 314 upvotes. 2009.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

-lm is a linker flag, so you should add it to the linking rule above (i.e., you added it to the wrong rule).

Comment: Knew it was a dumb mistake like that, thanks! Will accept when the time limit is up.

Comment: @Tyler There's more to it than that. -lm must come after the objects, as user611775 notes below. And your main.o rule will produce a.out rather than main.o because you are missing -o $@ ... You should be using default rules and setting CFLAGS=Wall -pedantic instead of putting them in the rules.

Answer (score 5):

Furthermore, library specifications have to come after the objects referencing them (cf. [Linker flags in wrong place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241683/linker-flags-in-wrong-place) ).