# Properly include GLib headers with autotools

Tags: autotools, glib

In my normal dev environment (ubuntu), I don't have any issues linking against GLib-2.0, however when I attempt to build on fresh install of Debian Squeeze, I run into errors linking GLib.

configure.ac:

```
...
AC_PROG_CC
AM_PROG_CC_C_O
CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -Wall -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c99 -pedantic"

PKG_CHECK_MODULES(MYAPP, [glib-2.0 >= 2.3.0  gthread-2.0])

LIBS="$LIBS $MYAPP_LIBS"

AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile src/Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

Autotools appears to pass the correct options to gcc:

`-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0`

However, running `make` I get a compile error: `undefined reference to 'g_list_free_full'`

To verify the libraries are actually installed:

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep glib
libglib2.0-0                    install
libglib2.0-data                 install
libglib2.0-dev                  install
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You should show us your `Makefile.am` (if using automake) or `Makefile.in` (if not). Also show `src/Makefile.am` or `src/Makefile.in`.

Comment: Full source can be found here: https://github.com/benlemasurier/stormfs I stripped some data from the post for brevity

Comment: You *MUST NOT* ASSIGN CFLAGS in configure.ac.  CFLAGS is a user variable, and the user running the configure script should not have their assignment of CFLAGS overridden.  See http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/User-Variables.html

Comment: curl/types.h is removed at [2ef7a28a71](https://github.com/bagder/curl/commit/2ef7a28a71). It'd better not to use it. Otherwise, it will not compile after Debian Squeeze.

Comment: Just curios, who is using `g_list_free_full`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something to notice:

```
   stormfs_LDADD = $(LIBS) $(LIBGCRYPT_LIBS)
>> stormfs_LDFLAGS = $(STORMFS_LIBS)
```

(See [Linker flags in wrong place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241683/linker-flags-in-wrong-place) here on SO.)
That ought to be:

```
stormfs_LDADD = ${LIBS} ${LIBGCRYPT_LIBS} ${STORMFS_LIBS}
```

(That is however sort of redundant because both LIBS and STORMFS_LIBS contain the same value, just as I looked at the generated Makefile.)

**Edit:**

```
nm -D /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so | grep g_list_free_full
0000000000042740 T g_list_free_full
```

So libglib.so (your path to it may vary) does include `g_list_free_full` in at least glib2-2.30.1. According to the documentation, this function is only available since glib2-2.28, but your installation is likely just too old. Best use (and preferably just one pkg dependency per variable, to ease detection of what exactly of the [deps] part could not be found):

```
#configure.ac
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([libgthread], [gthread-2.0])
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([libglib], [glib-2.0 >= 2.28])
```

Comment: thanks, src/Makefile.am now looks like: https://gist.github.com/1666483 However I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: g_list_free_full requires >=2.28.