# Environment variable to tell autotools to append libraries?

Tags: ld, autotools

Autotools knows about `target_LDFLAGS` and `target_LDADD`. The difference is that LDADD gets added later to the command line than LDFLAGS, and its the right place to put libraries (`-lfoo`). [See also this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241683/linker-flags-in-wrong-place)

Now, I can set the environment variable `LDFLAGS` before running `./configure`, and it is picked up. Is there something similar for `LDADD`? I want to do something like:

```
export LDADD="-lfoo"
./configure
make
```

and have `-lfoo` appear *after* all the object files while linking. I tried the above but it didn't work. LDFLAGS works, but puts the library at the wrong place. What can I do?

Comment: Did you try `./configure --help`? It doesn't mention `LDADD`, but it mentions `LIBS`.

Answer (score 2):

The [autoconf manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Preset-Output-Variables) suggests that these `"-lfoo"` options should be added to the `LIBS` variable, as described by `./configure --help`.

You could have: `AC_SUBST(target_LIBS, $LIBS)` in `configure.ac`, and in `Makefile.am` :

`target_LDADD = $(target_LIBS)`

The ideal, of course, would be for the configure script to set `target_LIBS` automatically, if possible...

Comment: Don't `AC_SUBST` the automake variables from the configure script, this is not how they should be used.

Comment: @DanielKO - `target_LIBS` is not an automake variable in this context. This is the correct way to pass configure-time values to automake.

Comment: yes, using variables that look like automake variables by a few characters is **indeed** the way to do it. Use target_LDFLAG too, and live more intensely.

Comment: I got confused, you gave bad advice. And you don't have a sense of humor. He was asking about changing the invocation of configure anyways, not editing it.